# Hibernate duplicated rows during select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, orm

Few month ago I've started my adventure with Hibernate 5. I'm creating a Spring Boot application which need to take data from database view.
I have created an JPA entity and write code responsible for running query and map results to ORM entity. The problem is that Hibernate generate proper query in traces, but returns duplicate of the first row as a list. Query created by Hibernate looks like:

```
select
    revenuesum0_.revenueId as revenueI1_9_,
    revenuesum0_.amount as amount2_9_,
    revenuesum0_.calculatedDate as calculat3_9_,
    revenuesum0_.revenueCalculatedDateId as revenueC4_9_,
    revenuesum0_.categoryName as category5_9_,
    revenuesum0_.timeSpan as timeSpan6_9_,
    revenuesum0_.title as title7_9_,
    revenuesum0_.userId as userId8_9_ 
from
    RevenueSummaryView revenuesum0_ 
where
    revenuesum0_.userId=?;
```

When I run it on DBeaver and in MySQL console it works, the result set is proper. Problem appear when I'm trying to take data using Java JPA Query execution. Code responsible for bug is here:

```
    package org.pbt.dao;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.pbt.HibernateUtil;
    import org.pbt.model.entity.ExpenseSummaryView;
    import org.pbt.model.filter.Filter;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import javax.persistence.Query;
    import java.util.List;


    @Repository
    public class ExpenseSummaryViewDAOImpl implements ExpenseSummaryViewDAO {
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();


        @Override
        public List<ExpenseSummaryView> getFiltered(Filter filter) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            String hql = "FROM ExpenseSummaryView WHERE userId = :userId ";

            if (filter.getStartDate() != null && filter.getEndDate() != null) {
                hql += "AND calculatedDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ";
            } else if (filter.getStartDate() != null) {
                hql += "AND calculatedDate >= :startDate ";
            } else if (filter.getEndDate() != null) {
                hql += "AND calculatedDate <= :endDate ";
            }

            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("userId", filter.getUserId());

            if (filter.getStartDate() != null && filter.getEndDate() != null) {
                query.setParameter("startDate", filter.getStartDate());
                query.setParameter("endDate", filter.getEndDate());
            } else if (filter.getStartDate() != null) {
                query.setParameter("startDate", filter.getStartDate());
            } else if (filter.getEndDate() != null) {
                query.setParameter("endDate", filter.getEndDate());
            }

            List<ExpenseSummaryView> expenseSummaryViews = (List<ExpenseSummaryView>) query.getResultList();
            session.close();

            return expenseSummaryViews;
        }
    }
```

In a debug whole expenseSummaryViews list elements have the same object reference. The JPA entity looks like:

```
package org.pbt.model.entity;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.LocalDate;


@Entity
@Table(name = "ExpenseSummaryView")
public class ExpenseSummaryView {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "expenseId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "expenseCalculatedDateId", nullable = false)
    private int calculatedDateId;

    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private double amount;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    @Column(name = "calculatedDate", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate calculatedDate;

    @Column(name = "categoryName", nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "timeSpan", nullable = false)
    private String timeSpan;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getCalculatedDateId() {
        return calculatedDateId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public LocalDate getCalculatedDate() {
        return calculatedDate;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public String getTimeSpan() {
        return timeSpan;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{id:" + id + ", calculatedDateId:" + calculatedDateId + ", userId:" + userId + ", title:" + title + ", amount:" + amount + ", calculatedDate:" + calculatedDate.toString() + ", categoryName:" + categoryName + "}";
    }
}
```

It is worth to mention that in very similar case I used hibernate for taking rows from another view on the same db in the same application and it works normally, but in above case it doesn't.

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Your code and mapping appear to be correct. Maybe look into your repository configuration? On a different matter, you could optimize the setParameter part as: `if (filter.getStartDate() != null) {
                query.setParameter("startDate", filter.getStartDate());
            } else if (filter.getEndDate() != null) {
                query.setParameter("endDate", filter.getEndDate());
            }`

Comment: Hi, problem was caused because there were no real ID available on database, the expenseId field was not real ID in DB, after change it, source code start works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was caused because there were no real ID available on database, the expenseId field was not real ID in DB, after change it, source code start works normally.